# linux system resource analyzer

Tags: linux, debian, monitoring

I have a debian 5 machine that is running php, apache, node.js, and mysql.

I would like some report-generating software that will show cpu, memory usage, and network traffic over time. something simple with graphs and a web interface would be optimal. Being able to do this on a per-process or per-service basis would also be very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints: Cacti, munin, MRTG. Wikipedia has an [overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems).

Comment: ended up trying out munin first. will try others and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

SvenW's answer is definitely the better option, but don't forget about simple command line tools like `sar`, `atop` (and `atopsar`) and hell, even `sysshot`.

Of course, if you want graphs for these you'll be rolling your own, but for a quick overview with little/no configuration, they're unbeatable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick setup, take a look at [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/). To do this on a per process, in a nearly exact way, you can use `gmetric`, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/gmetric --name process_name_CPU_usage --value $(ps --no-headers -p `pidof process_name` -o pcpu) --type float --unit percentage
/usr/bin/gmetric --name process_name_memory --value $(expr $(ps --no-headers -p `pidof process_name` -o rss) \* 1024) --type uint32 --unit bytes
```

and put it into a cron job:

```
* * * * * /path/to/gmetric.sh
```