# Monitor cpu usage (and perhaps memory using) for a single process simple as possible

Tags: linux, monitoring, process, graph

I'm searching the easiest way to monitor the cpu usage of a single process in linux.
Use ps and change output is the way i have, but maybe a monitor tool is better.
Also I want to plot the usage (nice look). graph and gnuplot are to ugly ;)
But plot is optional.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/298476/linux-system-resource-analyzer

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/395801/graphing-per-user-cpu-usage-on-a-linux-machine

Answer (score 3):

The top command can take a PID as input:

```
top -p <pid>
```

No graphs available then though, but you will see the change in CPU usage for this process over time.