# How to use top without interactivity?

Tags: cpu-usage, performance-monitoring, top

I want to periodically monitor the CPU usage and plot in time series. Not having much knowledge, I plan to use the top command, something like this question ([Monitor cpu usage (and perhaps memory using) for a single process simple as possible](https://serverfault.com/questions/422989/monitor-cpu-usage-and-perhaps-memory-using-for-a-single-process-simple-as-poss)). However, when I issue command like "top -c -p PID", I want it to output then exit automatically without manually type q or ctrl-c. And if not using top, what other command can achieve the same function without interactivity?

Comment: maybe look at sysstat package for tools related to collecting system metrics.

Comment: PS can do also the job

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor the things for particular process you can use command:

```
ps -flp <PID>
```

if you want to monitor overall performance of the system you can use `vmstat` from `sysstat` package:

```
vmstat 1 2
```

and get the second line (first is average from the server start)

Answer (score 0):

From "man top", I find that using the option "-b" and "-n" can solve the issue.